# Behaviour of nlargest(N) when N greater than number of groups?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have built a DataFrame from the following list

```
df_list_1 = [{"animal": "dog", "color": "red", "age": 4, "n_legs": 4,}, 
             {"animal": "dog", "color": "blue", "age": 4, "n_legs": 3},
             {"animal": "cat", "color": "blue", "age": 4, "n_legs": 4},
             {"animal": "dog", "color": "yellow", "age": 5, "n_legs":2},
             {"animal": "dog", "color": "white", "age": 4, "n_legs": 2},
             {"animal": "dog", "color": "black", "age": 4, "n_legs": 4},
             {"animal": "cat", "color": "brown", "age": 4, "n_legs": 4}]
```

I want now to get a new dataframe which shows only the top 4 entries (sorted by `age`) per group with the same `n_legs`.

To do this I tried

```
dfg = df_1.set_index(["animal", 'color']).groupby("n_legs")['age'].nlargest(4).reset_index()
```

But this gives me a dataframe where the column `n_legs` is dropped.

```
    animal  color   age
0   dog     red     4
1   dog     blue    4
2   cat     blue    4
3   dog     yellow  5
4   dog     white   4
5   dog     black   4
6   cat     brown   4
```

I guess this is because 4 is equal to the number of elements in the largest group.  In fact if I do

```
dfg = df_1.set_index(["animal", 'color']).groupby("n_legs")['age'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
```

I get the following

```
    n_legs  animal  color   age
0   2       dog     yellow  5
1   2       dog     white   4
2   3       dog     blue    4
3   4       dog     red     4
4   4       cat     blue    4
5   4       dog     black   4
```

Is this an intended behaviour?

Is there a way to always show the column even when using `nlargest(N)` with `N` greater than the number of elements in the biggest group?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can call `sort_values` before `groupby`. Then, you would just have to do `GroupBy.head(N)`.

Comment: I think it is bug.

Comment: thanks both.
That solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is [bug 16345](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16345).

Alternative solution working nice and obviously faster - first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then call [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
dfg = (df_1.sort_values(["animal", 'color','age'], ascending=[False, False, True])
          .groupby("n_legs")
          .head(4))
```